# Plot discrete events over time series (days of a year)

Tags: r

I hope I am able to phrase this correctly.

I have a vector of dates that represent an event occurring.
It kind of looks like this:

```
days_of_event <- c("2016-08-15", "2016-07-18", "2016-08-17", ...)
```

The class of the vector is `"Date"`.

I want make a plot where the x axis represents the days of the year (from `2016-01-01` to `2017-01-01`) and some kind of marker is added on the plot, when a event occurred.

I was able to create the values of the X axis with

```
days <- seq.Date(lubridate::ymd("2016-1-1"), lubridate::ymd("2017-1-1"), "days")
```

but I don't know where to go from here.

I am new to R and it is still very confusing, so every help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: package [incidence](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/incidence/vignettes/overview.html) may be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
days_of_event <- as.Date(c("2016-08-15", "2016-08-18", "2016-08-17"))

#Create a data.frame marking the dates of events
x <- data.frame(id = days_of_event, val = rep(1,length(days_of_event)))

#Create a data.frame with your time span (just a month in this example)
y <- data.frame(id = seq.Date(as.Date("2016-08-01"),as.Date("2016-09-01"), "days"))

#Join the two Frames and plot the result
plot(merge(y,x,by=c("id"),all.x=TRUE),las=2,col="red",pch=16,cex=1.5,ylab="",yaxt="n",xlab="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

days <- seq.Date(lubridate::ymd("2016-1-1"), lubridate::ymd("2017-1-1"), "days")
#randomly sample on or off, replace with your data
days_df = data.frame( days = days, event = sample(x = 0:1, size = length(days), replace = TRUE))

days_df %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = days, y = event))
```